# CodeIgniter How to use onsubmit event in form_open()

Tags: forms, codeigniter

In HTML, I can call a javascript function like below

```
 <form type="post" onsubmit ="return test()" >
 </form>
```

How do I call the same javascript function in

```
 form_open();
```

When form gets posted, I want function test to be called. How do I do above in CodeIgniter?

**Update**

x.html is my HTML page

```
   <form>
    </form>

    <?php $data = array('submit'=>"test()");
   echo form_open(x,$data);
  echo  form_close();
    ?>
```

Comment: You really should not be using event handlers in HTML attributes, but rather be using JS to bind to the event.

Answer (score 4):

In your template file x.html use

```
<?php $data = array('onsubmit' => "test()"); ?>
<?php echo form_open('email/send', $data); ?>
<?php echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Submit Post!'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

it works correctly

Comment: I had tried it like this but it is directly calling my controller.

Comment: @Noval Agung Prayogo:I have an HTML page, I have my function in JS file, I've linked it to my HTML. I want my js function to be called, when I click on submit button and I have my JS function in form tag but now, When I click on submit button, it is posting contents to controllers, instead it has to call my JS function first right.

Answer (score 2):

add it as array in 2nd param of `form_open()`

```
<?= form_open('email/send', array('onsubmit' => 'your js')); ?>
```

read http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: :I had tried it like this but it is directly calling my controller.

Comment: what do you mean by 'directly calling my controller?'. if you mean you call that funtion inner controller file. use `echo`, like `echo form_open(...)`

Comment: :I have an HTML page, I have my function in JS file, I've linked it to my HTML. I want my js function to be called, when I click on submit button and I have my JS function in form tag but now, When I click on submit button, it is posting contents to controllers, instead it has to call my JS function first right.

Answer (score 0):

should try this

```
  <?php echo form_open($base_url.'pjremove', "style='display:inline' onsubmit='confirm(your message)'"); ?>
```