# How to convert onsubmit to form_open

Tags: php, codeigniter, onsubmit

My code is like this:

```
<form action="http://<?php echo site_url();?>/loader/task1" onsubmit="return checkDifferance();" method="post">
```

How can I convert this onsubmit to form_open? How to improve the code below?

```
<?php echo form_open('loder/task1');?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter How to use onsubmit event in form\_open()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448882/codeigniter-how-to-use-onsubmit-event-in-form-open)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php echo form_open('loder/task1', array('onsubmit' => 'return checkDifferance();'));?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
echo form_open('loder/task1','onsubmit="return checkDifferance();" method="post"');
```

Comment: I don't want to write the method type in form_open right?

Comment: two methods available in CodeIgniter

Comment: Why using a array is better ? can you explain :) @wolfgang1983

Comment: look this link                       http://codeigniter-id.github.io/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form